# Java define class as enum value instead of other types

Tags: java

I'm newbie in using `enum`s in Java and I want to use that instead of other type such as `String` or `int`. in this below code I want to have some value as an `enum`, set that from class `Constructor` and then get that by `getter`, my code is not correct and after more Googling I can't seem fix it.

Thank you in advace.

```
public class SampleEvent {
    private enum path {
        LEFT ,
        RIGHT
    }

    public SampleEvent(path p) {
        path = p;
    }

    public enum getPath(){
        return path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a member variable of the type of the enum, and your `getPath` method should have a correct return type.

You must also make the enum `public`, otherwise it will not be possible to call the constructor from outside the class (code outside the class would have no access to the enum type).

```
public class SampleEvent {
    public enum Path {
        LEFT, RIGHT
    }

    // Member variable
    private Path path;

    // Constructor
    public SampleEvent(Path p) {
        path = p;
    }

    public Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jesper Would you advocate for the Path field to be final? That is if SampleEvent is meant to be immutable, of course.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, but I didn't want to put too much information in my answer. It's often a good idea to make classes immutable.

Answer (score 4):

Your code should be like below..

```
public class SampleEvent {
    public enum PATH {
        LEFT ,
        RIGHT
    }

    private PATH val;

    public SampleEvent(PATH p) {
        val = p;
    }

    public PATH getPath(){
        return val;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleEvent se = new SampleEvent(PATH.LEFT);
        System.out.println(se.getPath());
    }
}
```

and output is `LEFT`

Comment: If SampleEvent can be immutable, it's probably preferable to make it so: `private final path val;` I'd also make path enum name be "Path" to follow naming conventions.

Comment: And the Enum should be public.

Comment: @FildorThanks for the inputs

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public class SampleEvent {

    public enum Path {
        LEFT ,
        RIGHT
    }

    private Path path;

    public SampleEvent(SampleEvent.Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public SampleEvent.Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }
}
```